# What's CFRunLoop?

Tags: iphone, uikit

I would like to understand run loop more in-depth than what the reference provides.  Is there resources out there that discuss this in greater details?

Answer (score 0):

I found this reasonably good: [CFRunLoop Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html)

...and this: [Run Loops in the Threading Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html)

Comment: As mentioned, looking for more in-depth treatment than what's already in the reference.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet might be looking at the [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.15/CFRunLoop.c).  I just did a google search for "How cfrunloop works" and this question was the third hit after 5 minutes.